# displaying page 2 etc of multipage tiff

Tags: images

I have a multi-page TIFF file produced from scanning. When I open the file (Image Viewer), Next goes to the Next image file in the folder not the next image in the file. Is there a hidden option to see each of the images (Ubuntu 13.10).

I don't really want to split/convert the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can use `evince` for this. Right click the file and select `open with` → `Document Viewer` instead of the default Image Viewer (Eye-of-gnome).

Unfortunately `evince` does not have an option to easily move from one document to another...

Comment: It is only one document so that is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

XNViewMP can view multi-page tiff files. It's particularly suited to multi-page -tiffs made up of non-textual images.

[image]

The highlighted section in the image above has page keys, through which multi-page tiffs can be navigated.

Answer (score 1):

The `display` utility from the ImageMagick-6 suite of tools can be used to view a multi-page tiff file. I use the following command to view the tiff files scanned using a HP 8270 multi-function printer:

```
display -rotate 90 -resize 1920x1080 Musings.tif
```

The `display` utility has **many** command line options, of which I found the above necessary. `-resize`, which is a bit finicky as to what resolution it accepts, permits viewing the entire image at a reduced resolution without scrolling.

To turn pages, right-click anywhere on the image, then without releasing the button, move the cursor down to Next or Former on the context-menu, then release the button. I have not yet found a menu that directly moves to any page/image within the file; however, there may be a command-line option for selecting which images to view. (The `display` man page is rather cryptic due to its brevity.)

Also, the `tiff-tools` package has a number of utilities, of which the following are particularly useful:

```
tiffcp : copy or concatenate images from one tiff file to another,
         optionally selecting and resequencing images from the input file(s).
tiffinfo : display the metadata for every image in a tiff.
tiffsplit : split a tiff file into individual files, 
            each containing a single image.
```

Here is an example of using `tiffcp` to create a new tiff file containing selected images from one file and all images from another:

```
tiffcp Musings-1.tif,5,6,0,1,2,3,4  Musings-2.tif Musings_new.tif
```

The `tiff-tools` package also has a number of other utilities for editing and converting images in tiff files.

Comment: I have subsequently discovered that the `Evince` (`Atril` on Ubuntu MATE) `document viewer` is a much better option than `display`.